# Knockout.js observable notify 'always' and subscribe

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following code:

HTML:

```
<p>Age:
    <input data-bind="value:age" />
</p>
<p>Age has been changed: <span data-bind="text:ageChangeCount"></span> times</p>
```

JS:

```
function viewModel() {

    var self = this;

    self.age = ko.observable(10).extend({
        notify: 'always'
    }), 

    self.ageChangeCount = ko.observable(0),

    self.age.subscribe(function (val) {
        console.log('Someone has changed age');
        self.ageChangeCount(self.ageChangeCount() + 1);
    });

};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EstSiim/9majtx0h/

I am wondering why ageChangeCount wont increment when old age and new age are the same (when input looses focus)?

Comment: If you focus the field and then blur it *without editing the value*, the `change` event does not get triggered. Why should it? (In newer versions of knockout, you can use the `textInput: age` binding instead of `value: age`, there's a difference between the two when you are actually editing the value.)

Comment: This idea came from http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/13124/how-to-make-observable-property-to-notify-always-in-knockout.aspx .

Comment: That link includes a fiddle - does that fiddle work for you? Because it doesn't work for me, which makes me doubt the whole post...

Comment: There is also a small section in http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html  at the bottom of the page called Forcing observables to always notify subscribers. Maybe my English is not so good...

Comment: Look at the answer posted below by @haim770 . In general, you can force observables to always fire notifications (e.g. if you manually write `self.age(self.age())`, the counter will update), but in the specific case of "`<input>` value is changed but the new value is exactly the same as the old one", there's another part of knockout code which stops notifications from firing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `value` binding-handler is simply ignoring model updating when new value matches the old value. Hence, subscriptions wouldn't run as well.

See [Source](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/expressionRewriting.js#L176)

Comment: At a glance, it seems like that code is meant for the situation where the model updates and that value needs to be sent *to* the DOM, not the reverse?